# Font size chaning while button size change

Tags: java, swing

Is there any method which can customize font size of text on button when button size is being changed? Or do i have to implement `ComponentListener` for my button class?

Comment: What causes button size change?

Comment: program can run with given arguments- window size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a listener in order to know when the button size is being changed (idk what you mean by that but still), and you can change the font size by using `setFont()` however you'll still need to calculate the approrpiate size, etc. Check out a [related example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943672/automatic-dynamic-expansion-contraction-of-jtextarea-in-java) with a JTextArea instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the standard approach for handling component resizing for instance when the layout manager caused a component resize. In the `componentResized` method you could do:

```
float newSize = ...
myButton.setFont(myButton.getFont().deriveFont(newSize));
```